# Json.NET TypeNameHandling for reading only

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using the following `JsonSerializerSettings`:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
}
```

> Gets or sets how type name writing and reading is handled by the serializer.

I was wondering if there is any way to enable type name reading, but disable it during writing.

I am deserializing a list of abstract base classes, so I need the `$type` nodes on my JSON to be able to deserialize (using a custom SerializationBinder), but I don't want my responses to include their types and namespaces.

Note that I am referring to the (de)serialization in the context of **ASP.NET Web API** where I can only set my SerializerSettings on a global level on my JsonFormatter in `Configuration.Formatters` or on Controller level using `IControllerConfiguration`. These settings are always used for both reading and writing.

Comment: Please don't use another TypeNameHandling than `TypeNameHandling.None` when creating a Web API. Using `TypeNameHandling.Objects` might make your Web API vulnerable: https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html

Comment: @peter As the documentation states: `Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.` which is the case here as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this `TypeNameHandling` was only needed for a specific DTO, I just created a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyDTO);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var customSerializer = new JsonSerializer {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects, 
            Binder = new CustomSerializationBinder()
        };
        return customSerializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }
}
```

And registered it on my `JsonFormatter`:

```
Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new CustomJsonConverter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not `TypeNameHandling` is used may be defined on per `SerializeObject`/`DeserializeObject` basis. So just don't use these settings when you don't need that `$type`:

```
var typedJson = @"{""$type"":""ConsoleApp2.Program+TestData, ConsoleApp2"",""TestField"":0}";
var testData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(typedJson, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);    // <----- Notice no settings here
Console.WriteLine(json);

// Outputs:
//     {"TestField":0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I forgot to mention I am working in an ASP.NET WebAPI context, see my edited question